# RegEx for allowing min and max number of characters in a string

Tags: regex

I want to add the validation for following criteria

"Up to 256 alphanumeric characters - and _ allowed"

Answer (score 0):

Here is the regex

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9_]{0,255}$/
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use [`^[\w-]{0,255}$`](https://regex101.com/r/ZI5uEk/1)

This will match any word character `\w` *(which will match `a-zA-Z0-9_`)* and an hyphen in a character set repeated between 0 and 255 times.

Note that since you don't specify a minimum this would also allow an empty string.